# Workflow Rule Engine to implement rules engine in a ASP.NET Web Application?

Tags: validation, workflow-foundation, rule-engine

Can anyone share using WWF Workflow Rule Engine to implement rules engine in a ASP.NET Web Application?

Comment: My answer below was downvoted and deleted. I'm putting the link here because it is helpful and the tutorial is lengthy. If the page moves it should be locatable by title (Windows Workflow Tutorial: Rules-Driven .NET Applications ) or in various web archives: This article specifically addresses ASP.NET scenarios:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349785.aspx